# How to split a string every fourth delimiter?

Tags: vba, split

Is it possible to split a string every fourth delimiter?

We receive a text file that has one string containing several days data.

I would like to split once using the '|' as the delimiter, but different days data is joined by a comma.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Split4thdelim()
    Dim strOriginal as string
    Dim originalArry() as string
    Dim X as long

    strOriginal = "01/01/2020|user1,89|user2,90|user3,99,02/01/2020|user1,80|user2,85|user3,97,03/01/2020|user1,88|user2,96|user3,99"
    originalArry = split(strOriginal,"|")

    For X = originalArry(originalArry(Lbound)) to originalArry(originalArry(Ubound))
        Debug.Print originalArry(X)
    Next
End Sub
```

I would like to split it like this:

```
01/01/2020
user1,89
user2,90
user3,99
02/01/2020
user1,80
user2,85 
user3,97
03/01/2020
user1,88
user2,96
user3,99
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Split4thdelim()
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim originalArry() As String
    Dim X As Long, n As Long

    strOriginal = "01/01/2020|user1,89|user2,90|user3,99,02/01/2020|user1," & _
                  "80|user2,85|user3,97,03/01/2020|user1,88|user2,96|user3,99"

    'replace every fourth "," with chr(0)
    For X = 1 To Len(strOriginal)
        If Mid(strOriginal, X, 1) = "," Then
            n = n + 1
            If n Mod 4 = 0 Then Mid(strOriginal, X, 1) = Chr(0)
        End If
    Next X
    originalArry = Split(strOriginal, Chr(0))

    For X = LBound(originalArry) To UBound(originalArry)
        Debug.Print Join(Split(originalArry(X), "|"), vbLf)
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Try,

```
Sub Split4thdelim()
    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim originalArry() As String
    Dim X As Long
    Dim vSplit, s As String, s2 As String
    Dim vR()
    Dim n As Long

    strOriginal = "01/01/2020|user1,89|user2,90|user3,99,02/01/2020|user1,80|user2,85|user3,97,03/01/2020|user1,88|user2,96|user3,99"
    originalArry = Split(strOriginal, "|")

    For X = LBound(originalArry) To UBound(originalArry)
        'Debug.Print originalArry(X)
        s = originalArry(X)
        If InStr(s, "/") And InStr(s, ",") Then
            n = n + 2
            vSplit = Split(s, ",")
            s2 = vSplit(UBound(vSplit))
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n - 1) = Replace(s, "," & s2, "")
            vR(n) = s2
        Else
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n)
            vR(n) = s
        End If
    Next
    Range("a1").Resize(n) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(vR)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Do it manually:

```
Sub Split4thdelim()
   Dim strOriginal As String
   Dim Token As New Collection
   Dim strToken As String
   Dim X As Long

   strOriginal = "01/01/2020|user1,89|user2,90|user3,99,02/01/2020|user1,80|user2,85|user3,97,03/01/2020|user1,88|user2,96|user3,99"

   Dim Pos As Long
   Dim strTemp As String
   Pos = InStr(1, strOriginal, "user")
   Token.Add Mid(strOriginal, 1, Pos - 2)
   strOriginal = Right(strOriginal, Len(strOriginal) - Pos + 1)

   While Pos > 0
      Pos = InStr(2, strOriginal, "user")
      Token.Add Mid(strOriginal, 1, Pos - 2)

      strOriginal = Right(strOriginal, Len(strOriginal) - Pos + 1)
      Pos = InStr(2, strOriginal, "user")
      Token.Add Mid(strOriginal, 1, Pos - 2)

      strOriginal = Right(strOriginal, Len(strOriginal) - Pos + 1)
      Pos = InStr(2, strOriginal, "user")
      If Pos = 0 Then 'no more user, so this is the last set
         Token.Add Right(strOriginal, Len(strOriginal) - Pos)
      Else
         strTemp = Left(strOriginal, Pos - 2)
         strOriginal = Right(strOriginal, Len(strOriginal) - Pos + 1) 'save new strOriginal

         Pos = InStr(1, strOriginal, ",")
         strToken = Mid(strTemp, 1, Pos)
         strTemp = Right(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - Pos)
         Pos = InStr(1, strTemp, ",")
         If Pos = 0 Then
            Pos = InStr(1, strTemp, "|")
         End If
         strToken = strToken + Mid(strTemp, 1, Pos - 1)
         Token.Add strToken

         Token.Add Right(strTemp, Len(strTemp) - Pos)
      End If
   Wend

   Dim strItem As Variant
   For Each strItem In Token
      Debug.Print strItem
   Next strItem
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

or ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Split4thdelim()

    Dim strOriginal As String
    Dim vCounter As Long
    Dim vNewElement As String
    Dim vCommaCount As Long

    strOriginal = "01/01/2020|user1,89|user2,90|user3,99,02/01/2020|user1,80|user2,85|user3,97,03/01/2020|user1,88|user2,96|user3,99"

    vNewElement = ""
    vCommaCount = 0
    For vCounter = 1 To Len(strOriginal)
        If Mid$(strOriginal, vCounter, 1) <> "|" And Mid$(strOriginal, vCounter, 1) <> "," Then
            vNewElement = vNewElement & Mid$(strOriginal, vCounter, 1)
        Else
            If Mid$(strOriginal, vCounter, 1) = "|" Then
                Debug.Print vNewElement
                vNewElement = ""
                vCommaCount = 0
            ElseIf Mid$(strOriginal, vCounter, 1) = "," Then
                vCommaCount = vCommaCount + 1
                If vCommaCount = 2 Then
                    Debug.Print vNewElement
                    vNewElement = ""
                    vCommaCount = 0
                Else
                    vNewElement = vNewElement & Mid$(strOriginal, vCounter, 1)
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print vNewElement

End Sub
```

[image]